# Javascript getElementsByClassName returning a weird collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I have a web page crawler that I'm using puppeteer to crawl with. I trying to grab all the elements in the DOM using `getElementsByClassName` however it returning a wonky collection. I expected to received an array of html elements and their children.

```
 (async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const opportunities = [];

    let url = "https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc"
    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    const oportunitiesDOM = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("opportunity"));
    });

    console.log(oportunitiesDOM);
    oportunitiesDOM.forEach(opo => {
        console.log(opo);
        // crawlOpo(opo)
    });

    browser.close();

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

the data being outputted is:

```
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko169' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko187' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko205' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko223' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko241' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko259' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko277' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko295' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko313' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko331' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko349' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko367' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko385' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko403' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko421' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko439' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko457' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko475' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko493' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko511' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko529' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko547' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko565' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko583' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko601' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko619' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko637' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko655' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko673' }
{ __ko__1568043867697: 'ko691' }
```

I cant seem to figure out why this is and how to correct this. I do know the website I'm crawling is using `React` and I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: It's more complex than you think. That website is using a combination of knockout and react.

Comment: @Jamiec so how do i go about grabbing the collection of elements by className? I can successfully grab one single opportunity and the associated data.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

[`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only be used with serializable data. This is data that can be passed from the browser environment to the Node.js environment via `JSON.stringify` (like strings, numbers, etc.). DOM nodes cannot be transferred to the Node.js environment in this way.

#### Solution

If you want to query elements elements, you need to use [`page.$$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) instead. Quote from the docs:

> The method runs `document.querySelectorAll` within the page. If no elements match the selector, the return value resolves to `[]`.

**Code Sample**

After executing the following code, `oportunitiesDOM` is an array containing the referenced DOM nodes with the class `opportunity`:

```js
const oportunitiesDOM = await page.$$('.opportunity');
```